# DateTime.TryParseExact not working as expected

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

Can anyone explain why the following snippet returns true?

According to the docs for [The "d" custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier), "A single-digit day is formatted without a leading zero." So why doesn't TryParseExact fail when I give it a single-digit day with a leading zero?

```
DateTime x;
return DateTime.TryParseExact
(
    "01/01/2001",
    @"d\/MM\/yyyy",
    null,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out x
);
```

**UPDATE**

I think maybe I was unclear originally. What I am really trying to get at is: **Why does TryParseExact accept some values that don't match exactly?** from all of the documentation I have seen, 'd' matching '01' and '1' is just as much a bug as if 'MM' matched 'March' as well as '03'. **The issue here isn't that the values are equivalent, its that they don't match the format.**

The relevant snippets of documentation are:

- From [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx): **The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly.**
- From [The 'd' Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier): **A single-digit day is formatted without a leading zero.**

It seems abundantly clear to me that '01' has a leading 0, and therefore doesn't exactly match 'd'.

Comment: Any scenario in which it may cause harm?

Comment: By your logic, the inverse should fail as well: `DateTime.TryParseExact("1/01/2001", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out x);`

Comment: @BFree: The case that you mentioned already does fail, as it should.

Comment: @veredesmarald: I just tested in on my machine (VS2010 - .Net 4) and it runs just fine...

Comment: @BFree: I am also running VS2010/.Net4. `DateTime.TryParseExact("1/01/2001", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out x);` returns `false`  and `DateTime.ParseExact("1/01/2001", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);` throws `FormatException`...

Comment: @veredesmarald: Oops my bad, I was outputting the date, and forgot that it was a TryParse. I was just looking at the month/day part and it seemed like it's working. You're right though, it does in fact fail, which means it's more than likely a bug... Good catch.

Comment: Scenario in which this causes harm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227756/datetime-tryparseexact

Answer (score 8):

From the .NET 4 source in DateTimeParse.ParseByFormat():

```
case 'd':
    // Day & Day of week 
    tokenLen = format.GetRepeatCount();
    if (tokenLen <= 2) { 
        // "d" & "dd" 

        if (!ParseDigits(ref str, tokenLen, out tempDay)) { 
            if (!parseInfo.fCustomNumberParser ||
                !parseInfo.parseNumberDelegate(ref str, tokenLen, out tempDay)) {

                result.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind.Format, "Format_BadDateTime", null);
                return (false); 
            }
        } 
        if (!CheckNewValue(ref result.Day, tempDay, ch, ref result)) { 
            return (false);
        }
    }
    else
    {...}
```

The parser lumps "d" and "dd" together.

Comment: In case you're wondering, the .NET code (that part which Microsoft shares) is freely available at [http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It appears that behavior is by design, and I think it works that way to be consistent with other string formatting options.

Take the following example:

```
//Convert DateTime to string
string dateFormat = "d/MM/yyyy";
string date1 = new DateTime(2008, 10, 5).ToString(dateFormat);
string date2 = new DateTime(2008, 10, 12).ToString(dateFormat);

//Convert back to DateTime
DateTime x1, x2;
DateTime.TryParseExact(date1, dateFormat, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out x1);
DateTime.TryParseExact(date2, dateFormat, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out x2);

Console.WriteLine(x1);
Console.WriteLine(x2);
```

In the first part, `ToString()` outputs a two digit day for October 12th, because it wouldn't make much sense to just write out a single digit day (and which digit would it pick, the 1 or the 2?). So since the "d" represents ***one OR two*** digit days when converting to a string, it would have to work the same way when converting back to `DateTime`. If it didn't, the conversion back to `DateTime` in `TryParseExact` in my example would fail, and that would definitely not be an expected behavior.

I would say that if you really need to match a d/MM/yyyy format exactly, you could probably use a regex to validate the string and then pass it through `Parse`, `TryParse` or `TryParseExact` (depending on how good your regex is, since it would have to handle leap years, 30/31 days, etc if you wanted to use `Parse`).

Comment: The specifier 'd' doesn't mean "output a single digit", it means "output the day without leading zeroes". Obviously days larger than 9 will always be printed with two digits. Both of the strings you get in step one conform exactly to the format, so naturally they should parse successfully.

Comment: @veredesmarald Right, but if TryParseExact worked the way you are expecting it to as you stated in the question, then my TryParseExact on date2 would fail. That would be terribly confusing to deal with. If ToString works one way, Parse needs to work the same way as well.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I suggest you go read the [specification of 'd'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dSpecifier). '12' doesn't have any leading zeroes, so it matches just fine.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question a bit. I thought you were trying to validate a string that just had a single digit day, I missed that you were mainly concerned with that leading zero. Yea, you might be onto something here. I'll have to think about this one a bit...

Comment: I think my original post was maybe not explicit enough about what was unexpected, I have added some more detail accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`TryParseExact` is just trying to be flexible in this case I guess. But the "d" vs "dd" should and would work as advertised when you are converting date to string using a format specifier.

Comment: There is something very unsettling about methods with 'Exact' in the name trying to be 'flexible'...

Comment: Unlike the numeric data types for which they have just Parse and TryParse, date is a weird type because of all the different formats it could have. Parse tries to guess it but ParseExact is there so you can say 01/02/2001 is mm/dd/yyyy and not dd/mm/yyyy. This flexibility that it allows doesn't hurt any case so I don't think it's a bug and it's totally intentional, don't you think?

Comment: Well since the behaviour doesn't match the [documentation of the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) ([...] must match a specified format exactly.), I would argue that it is, technically, a bug (maybe a bug in the documentation!). I would argue that the correct tool for saying 01/02/2001 is dd/mm or mm/dd is to use the regular Parse method with the appropriate culture.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it doesn't fail because `TryParseExact` is smart enough to know that '01' == '1'.

Comment: Except that it doesn't. If I wanted to accept 01 I would have used 'dd' instead of 'd'.

Comment: Yeah, I agree - the word "Exact" is in the method name so it should respect your format. But I think it's just trying to be more friendly (or maybe it's a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Because a single 'd' means that your DateTime value will be converted to as short value as possible, i.e. without leading zero if there's no necessity for it. I suppose it shouldn't fail when you're converting from string to DateTime because the main purpose of TryParseExact's format string is to help to convert to DateTime, i.e. it serves like a **hint**, it's not intended to validate string format.

You can use [RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) if you still need hardcore string format validation.

Comment: Its **not a hint**, and **is intended to validate format**. The documentation of TryParseExact explicitly states: **"The format of the string representation must match a specified format exactly."**

Comment: @veredesmarald: oh, I see. Then you've just answered your own question. You can report a bug in TryParseExact to Microsoft, though I doubt they will fix it, they have a lot more awesome work to do :)

Comment: The real reason they wouldn’t “fix” the method is because it would break a *ton* of things. Instead, they need to fix the documentation of “d” to say that it behaves differently when used in a format string for parsing.