# Parsing non-standard date formats with DateTime.TryParseExact

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime-format

Hi Im trying to parse date strings like "1012012", "1st January 2012".

1. read the Api It says to use d,%d where the date does not have a leading 0. Cant get it working for dates like "1012012"
2. trying to use "d MMM YYYY" for  "1st January 2012", what do I use so 'st', 'th' works?

   ```
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Globalization;

   namespace test
   {
     class Script
     {
       static public void Main(string [] args)
       {

           //String dateString = "9022011";  // q1
           String dateString = "9th February 2011";  //q2
           System.DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
           string[] format = { "ddMMyyyy", "d MMM yyyy" }; // what would be the correct format strings?

           if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,format,new CultureInfo("en-AU"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
                           {
               Console.Out.WriteLine(date.ToString());
           } 
                           else
                           {
               Console.Out.WriteLine("cant convert");
           }
        }
     }

   }
   ```

Comment: I don't think you can do the first. I'm quite sure the `d` is "greedy" and tries to take 2 digits. I don't think ParseExact uses a regular expression able to "backtrack" and try another "option". Clearly first type of dates can be parsed manually quite easily :-)

Comment: yeah I padded a 0 and doing it that way... the API reads harder than hieroglyphics sometimes...

Comment: Discussion about 'd': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905728/datetime-tryparseexact-not-working-as-expected. Seems like this behaviour could finally be considered as a bug in BCL.

Comment: @P H I've edited your post to make more meaningful title.

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateString = "1st February 2011";
DateTime date;
var replaced = dateString.Substring(0,4)
                         .Replace("nd","")
                         .Replace("th","")
                         .Replace("rd","")
                         .Replace("st","")
                         + dateString.Substring(4);

DateTime.TryParseExact(replaced, "d MMMM yyyy",
                       new CultureInfo("en-us"), DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, 
                       out date);
```

should do the trick (sorry the 'th' is nasty) - you have to take some care with the st (August) - just remove it only from the first few appearances:

Comment: sorry guys updated my answer and it is working - BTW: a explanations for the dowvote woud be realy cool

Comment: I upvoted, because this really is the only possibility. However, your code doesn't work for the first, second and third day of the month. I think that's the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: but what happens for 1st, 3rd.  any way without having  a bunch of String.Replaces?

Comment: just add them to my second line - it's not that many. Or use a RegEx to replace/reformat but that would be overkill IMHO

Comment: @P H: No, see my answer - there is no format specifier that understands "1st" or "4th"...

Comment: I updated the code and tested it with "1st, 3rd, 5th" - works like a charm

Comment: right - here we go .... I hope that's it (rather hard to remeber as a non native english speaker ...)

Comment: Substring(0,4).Replace("th","").Replace("st","").             .Replace("rd","") would be smart for the second date format, I'll live with that. But cant nail the first format, ie the date without leading  0. Sorry Guys i need 15 points to Upvote still :)    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx says d, %d
The day of the month. Single-digit days do not have a leading zero. The application specifies "%d" if the format pattern is not combined with other format patterns. cant make sense of it. Excel has made life harder

Comment: @P H: You have to use "%d" only if it the only format specifier in the format string. This tells the engine not to look for a default format specifier named "d" but to understand that "d" should be interpreted as a custom format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

1. I don't think this can be done. The parser processes your input left-to-right, so if it sees "1012012" it will think the day is 10, and then fail the parse because there's not enough characters left, even if the format string is "dMMyyyy". It would need some kind of backtracking to consider the possibility that the day is 1, but it doesn't seem to do that unfortunately.

   It is however fairly simple to use a custom regex to parse this format. The regex parser does use backtracking so it will correctly consider both options:

   ```
   string input = "1012012";
   Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"^(?<day>\d{1,2})(?<month>\d{2})(?<year>\d{4})$");
   if( m.Success )
   {
       DateTime d = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["year"].Value),
                                 Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["month"].Value),
                                 Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["day"].Value));
   }
   ```

   Another option would be to simple add a leading zero if the length of the string is seven:

   ```
   string input = "1012012";
   if( input.Length == 7 )
       input = "0" + input;
   DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
   ```
2. Rather than attempting to do multiple find and replaces as in the other answers, you can use the fact that the exact format of the string is known. It starts with one or two digits, followed by two letters, followed by the month and the year. So you could extract the date like this:

   ```
   string input = "1st January 2012";
   int index = char.IsNumber(input, 1) ? 2 : 1;
   input = input.Substring(0, index) + input.Substring(index + 2);
   DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "d MMMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   ```

   Of course, this will accept dates that have pure nonsense in those positions, like "1xx January 2012", but I'm not sure if that's a problem in your case.

   Also be sure to pass the appropriate `CultureInfo` if the input can hold non-English month names.

If you can get either format without knowing in advance which you're getting, you'll need a simple check to see which method to use beforehand. Strings in the first format will always be 7 or 8 characters, and strings in the second format will always be longer, so this should be easy to test. Another method would be to check if the string contains any non-numeric characters (in which case it's the long format).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse culture specific date strings you should use a matching culture. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` isn't a good idea, because it will only work with English strings.
However, what you are trying to do is not possible only with format specifiers, because there is no for the day that can parse the "th", "st" etc. strings. You will have to remove them manually beforehand.

Comment: as did I - but thanks to those nice downvoters my answer well go down the train ... I hate those buggers that don't even explain their vote

Comment: @Marshal: The downvotes on your answer are all explained by my comment. How do you explain your downvote on my answer?