# Regex not able to detect ,(comma)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to validate date string and for that I have written following regex string

```
[0-3]*\d{1}(st|nd|rd|th)?[\s\-\/]?(Jan|January|Feb|February|Mar|March|Apr|April|May|May|Jun|June|Jul|July|Aug|August|Sep|September|Oct|October|Nov|November|Dec|December|[0-1]?\d{1})[\s\-\/,]?(\d{4}|\d{2})
```

string input for my regex is `"31st March, 2018"`

I have already included `,`(comma character) in my regex string (the `[\s\-\/,]` part) but above input fails to validate.

Can anyone point out what correction is needed in above regex string so that it can detect `,`(comma) character in string?

Comment: Why regex though and not just `DateTime.TryParse(input, "dd MMMM yyyy")` ? - eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227800/2598770

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Validate a DateTime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371987/how-to-validate-a-datetime-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the space between the comma and the year. You should add \s? after the block that matches the comma.

```
[0-3]?\d{1}(st|nd|rd|th)?[\s\-\/]?(Jan|January|Feb|February|Mar|March|Apr|April|May|May|Jun|June|Jul|July|Aug|August|Sep|September|Oct|October|Nov|November|Dec|December|[0-1]?\d{1})[\s\-\/,]?\s?(\d{4}|\d{2})
```

Also, you need not scape characters inside **[]**, or specify a quantifier for matching only one character, so you can just change your regex to:

```
[0-3]?\d(st|nd|rd|th)?[ -/]?(Jan|January|Feb|February|Mar|March|Apr|April|May|May|Jun|June|Jul|July|Aug|August|Sep|September|Oct|October|Nov|November|Dec|December|[0-1]?\d)[ -/,]?\s?(\d{4}|\d{2})
```

[demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b0-3%5d%3f%5cd%28st%7cnd%7crd%7cth%29%3f%5b+-%2f%5d%3f%28Jan%7cJanuary%7cFeb%7cFebruary%7cMar%7cMarch%7cApr%7cApril%7cMay%7cMay%7cJun%7cJune%7cJul%7cJuly%7cAug%7cAugust%7cSep%7cSeptember%7cOct%7cOctober%7cNov%7cNovember%7cDec%7cDecember%7c%5b0-1%5d%3f%5cd%29%5b+-%2f%2c%5d%3f%5cs%3f%28%5cd%7b4%7d%7c%5cd%7b2%7d%29&i=31st+March%2c+2018)

**PS**: I don't really know much of C#, so can't speak for what others recommend using Datetime, but sounds like it may be worth checking out.

Comment: yes. Your answer made me realize the mistake I was doing. Thanks!!